# Give a number $x$ such that $139x + 1$ is divisible by 1111

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

> Give a number $x$ such that $139x + 1$ is divisible by 1111.

So this is a question of my abstract algebra homework, but not sure how to get started. I thought of doing something with $139x = -1$ mod $1111$, but the solution says: $x=-139^{-1} \in (\mathbb{Z}/1111\mathbb{Z})^{*}$. However I have no idea where $-139^{-1}$ is coming from... They conclude this numbers equals 1103, but without any explanation. 
Maybe someone could clarify this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$(139,1111)=?$$

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: It seems that the problem is to find an x such that 139 x + 1 is divisible by 1111.

Comment: If you know the chinese remainder theorem , you can slightly simplify the exercise by solving the congruence $139x\equiv -1$ modulo $11$ and modulo $101$. If the answer $8$ is correct, we must however have $139\equiv 1\mod 1111$, in other words $1111|139x-1$. The solution to the "139x+1"-variant  is $-8\equiv 1103\mod 1111$

Comment: Your title is still wrong.

Comment: My title is exactly the exercise as stated in the book.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I think, the book gives the inverse of $139$ modulo $1111$ as a hint to solve $139x\equiv -1\mod 1111$

Comment: @Katie, if your title is correct, then just take $x=1111$. Of course, $139x=139\cdot 1111$ is divisible by $1111$.

Comment: Oh crap. Sorry guys...

Answer (score 1):

Let's see. All congruence are $\bmod 1111$.

$139x\equiv -1$

Divide $1111$ by $139$, quotient = $7$, remainder =$138$. Multiply by one more than the quotient, thus $×8$:

$1112x \equiv 1x \equiv -8$

So $x\equiv -8 \bmod 1111$ making $1103$ the smallest positive solution.

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, the solution $x=8$ of $$139x\equiv 1\mod 1111$$ can relatively easy been detected. This menas that $x=-8\equiv 1103\mod 1111$ solves $$139x\equiv -1\mod 1111$$ Using the chinese remainder theorem, the numbers get somewhat smaller, making the solutions slightly easier.

Comment: Note that $8$ is the inverse of $139$ modulo $1111$, which gives the solution $-8$ immediately.